# nuget package dependency init.ps1 run order

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I have two nuget packages, Inner and Outer. 
Both have init.ps1 file which are to be run when adding the packages to a solution. Both of the init.ps1 files print out that it is being run.

The `.nuspec` file for Outer has a dependency on Inner like so:

```
<dependencies>
      <dependency id="Inner"  version="1.0.0" />
</dependencies>
```

When i install Outer in a project the logs in the console look like

```
Successfully installed 'Inner 1.0.0' to Project
Successfully installed 'Outer 1.0.0' to Project
Executing script file '.....Inner\tools\Init.ps1'...
init.ps1 in Outer called
init.ps1 in Inner called
Executing nuget actions took 2.08 sec
```

This seems to imply that the Outer init.ps1 gets executed before the Inner init.ps1 file.

Does anyone know if this is guaranteed? I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: Interesting. I would have expected the inner script to run first

Comment: Same here, i think it's safe to assume the ordering in the output window.

Comment: Might be quickest to look here for answers https://github.com/nuget/nuget.client